# passing data back with multiple viewControllers using Delegates

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been successfully learning  how to use Delegates. To date, I have learnt how to pass data to a secondViewController using storyBoards via the prepareForSegue method and then return data from the secondViewController back to first ViewController using Delegates.

The problem is when I create a thirdViewController as follows:
ViewController >> secondViewController >> thirdViewController.
(the delegate protocol is set in the thirdViewController)

My delegate works fine passing data from thirdViewController to secondViewController. The problem is when passing from secondViewController back to the viewController

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

SecondViewController *page2 = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
[[segue identifier] isEqual:@"page2"];
page2 = [segue destinationViewController];
page2.delegate = self; // this is the problem ??
```

}

The error i get is as follows: Property 'delegate' not found.
Is the problem that Delegates don't work in multiple views (in a chain) like this ??

Answer (score 0):

Several hints:

1. `SecondViewController *page2 = [[Page2 alloc]init];`
   What's the relationship between `SecondViewController` and `Page2`?
2. Make sure you defined `delegate` in `SecondViewController`.
3. Make sure you `#import "SecondViewController.h"` in `viewController.m`.

Comment: @anO thanks for the hints and yes I changed the error on hint 1. Nevertheless, no luck. I've re written the code again - this time there are no errors but again I have the same problem - any other ideas ??

Comment: @anO I've now found out that you can't chain delegate messages. So what I was trying to do was not possible. What I meant by "same problem" was that the delegate message can not be passed from the thirdController to the secondViewController and viewController. I know I can do this with NSNotification but I was trying to do it with Delegates.

Comment: I don't see why you can't. Just call `[delegate delegateMethodOfVC1]` in vc1's `-delegateMethodOfVC2` implementation wherein `delegate = vc`.