# Passing Data From Modal View To Another View

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently making an app that asks the user to enter information in a modal view, and that data needs to be accessed in a different view. Here is the set up:

[image]

In my `New Exercise Controller`, the user will enter the information and I need to be able to use it to create cells in my `New Workout View Controller`. How do I pass the data from my modal view back into this other view?

Comment: @lostintranslation That's in obj-c. I'm looking for a solution in Swift

Comment: Here is one is swift. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358023/pass-data-back-from-a-popped-viewcontroller-using-swift

Comment: And another. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522912/passing-data-back-from-view-controllers-xcode-v6b5-swift

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you share data between view controllers and other objects in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift)